# Default Value for DATETIME column in SQL Server Management Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, ssms-2017

Is it possible to create a table with a column that has type `DATETIME` and give it a default value such as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or `GETDATE()`? Is there another way to do this?

Screenshot from SSMS 2017

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: use SYSDATETIME() and define your field as DATETIME2(7): it's way more accurate than DATETIME and GETDATE()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define a constraint using TSQL:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD CONSTRAINT DF_TableName DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR ColumnName
```